# iOS simple authentication

Tags: ios, authentication

I'm new and trying to figure out some simple task.

I have two view controllers.

First one is the Login screen.

It has two fields and a login button.

If the user types in username and password correct, I just want to direct them to the next view.

Right now if I click the login button it will just go to the second screen.

I was wondering how I can authenticate the username and password (that can be hardcoded) and just if it's not correct then don't go to the next screen. If it is correct then go to the next screen.

I know it's simple but I can't find anything for some reason.

Header file
    #import

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userNameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
- (IBAction)LoginButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)backgroundClick:(id)sender;

@end
```

main file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize userNameField, passwordField;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];


    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




- (IBAction)LoginButton:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)backgroundClick:(id)sender {
    [userNameField resignFirstResponder];
    [passwordField resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to check your username & password then you should check like this in your method

```
- (IBAction)LoginButton:(id)sender {

    if([userNameField.text isEqualToString:@"username"] && [passwordField.text isEqualToString:@"pwd"]){

    NewViewController *newViewController=[[NewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:newViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
    else {

      NSLog(@"username or password is correct");

     }

}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but it still just goes straight to the  next view controller even when I put nothing in the two fields.

Comment: you should check for empty also

Comment: for example `if ([userNameField.text length] > 0 || userNameField.text != nil )`

Comment: My problem was that I just had it connected automatically. When I run it now it works but when I put in the correct username and password it crashes.

Comment: are you creating this new viewController with nib?

Comment: if you are using storyboard then do like this `UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"mystoryboard" bundle:nil];
NewViewController* newViewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController"];`

Comment: Yes I have a viewcontroller called HomeScreen. If I segue or just connect the login button to it then It will just go to the screen without authentication.

Comment: you should only segue if you username or password is correct not otherwise

Comment: That is my question then. How do I segue only if the username and password are correct and if otherwise just display an error of course.

Comment: well to do that you need to define the segue from first view to the second view with the identifier, and performsegue with this identifier when your condition is true something like this `[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"identifiername" sender:self];`

Comment: I actually found another soluction with -(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier and it worked now. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

In your

```
- (IBAction)LoginButton:(id)sender {
}
```

method, you need to implement something like this:

```
if([userNameField.text isEqualToString:@"userName"] && [passwordField.text isEqualToString:@"password"]){
    NSLog)@"successful login");
    //then load your new view
    YourViewController *yourVC=[[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self presentViewController:yourViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Invalid UserName Password");
    UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login Failed"    
                           message:@"Invalid user name and/or password"
                          delegate:self 
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                 otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```